# Create an exception message in a new window on Java, not on the console

Tags: exception

I know how to create an exception that appears in the console, but I want to create a new window that throws an exception so it will be visible to the user.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Never mind I handled it.
Just use this code:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String message);
```